# BLDC motors,and it signals

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

For changing speed of a BLDC motor,Which kind of signals should i send it?and wich parameters define this signal?
Wahts a duty cycle for a signal?sorry for bad english

Comment: Hello and welcome to EE.SE, Maryam. Please take your time and take the tour: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and rephrase your question, including already dome reasearch by your side.

Answer (score 0):

Change the frequency of the signal.
[image]